# What is the time complexity of floorEntry() method of NavigableMap?

Tags: java, sortedmap

If I have a `NavigableMap` already formed. What will be the time required for a `floorEntry()` operation to execute? will it be `O(1)` or `O(logn)`?

for example:

If I have a `NavigableMap` with n intervals, and I use `map.floorEntry(k)` for some random `k`, what will be the time complexity of the execution of the operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NavigableMap` is an interface, so I can't answer for any implementation of that interface. However, for the `TreeMap` implementation, `floorEntry()` requires `log(n)` time.

The Javadoc of `TreeMap` only states that

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations

but the implementation of `floorEntry()` is similar to the implementation of `get()` in terms of complexity.

Both call a helper method (`get()` calls `getEntry()` and `floorEntry()` calls `getFloorEntry()`) that performs most of the logic, and both of the helper methods have a while loop that advances to the left or right child in each iteration, until it finds what it is looking for or reaches a leaf. Thus the required time is the depth of the tree - `O(log(n))`.

Here are the implementations of `getEntry()` and `floorEntry()`:

```
/**
 * Returns this map's entry for the given key, or {@code null} if the map
 * does not contain an entry for the key.
 *
 * @return this map's entry for the given key, or {@code null} if the map
 *         does not contain an entry for the key
 * @throws ClassCastException if the specified key cannot be compared
 *         with the keys currently in the map
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified key is null
 *         and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator
 *         does not permit null keys
 */
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            p = p.left;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            p = p.right;
        else
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Gets the entry corresponding to the specified key; if no such entry
 * exists, returns the entry for the greatest key less than the specified
 * key; if no such entry exists, returns {@code null}.
 */
final Entry<K,V> getFloorEntry(K key) {
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
        if (cmp > 0) {
            if (p.right != null)
                p = p.right;
            else
                return p;
        } else if (cmp < 0) {
            if (p.left != null) {
                p = p.left;
            } else {
                Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                while (parent != null && ch == parent.left) {
                    ch = parent;
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                return parent;
            }
        } else
            return p;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks. also can there be any way to create a hash function that may do the job of floor entry in o(1) time?

Comment: @Neil Hash functions are not relevant to `NavigableMap`s. They are relevant to `HashMap`s, which don't have a `floorEntry` method, since they are not sorted.

Comment: I am aware of that. I was talking about merging the functionalities, not the ready made functions. 

Like creating a structure where the number line is divided into non-overlapping continuous intervals and each interval point to one value as we may decide.

and upon entering any value that lies in one of the interval, we get the value the interval is pointing to in o(1) time.

Comment: @Neil I don’t think there is such implementation, so you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Neil If I understand you correctly you want to divide the hash values into multiple intervals. That could only work, if the hashCode for your key would produce values in the same order as the keys should be sorted and don't change too much for "near" keys. But such a hashCode would be pretty bad, because it could very easily lead to many collisions.